# Modal presentation view in objective C is displaying NULL when I display NSLog(@"formView : %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

When I want to see all the views in my navigation controller when I open a second view in formSheet style from a first view, it displays me (null).

For example:

I open my second view modally in popover mode:

```
FormViewController *destViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"formView"];
destViewController.delegate = self;
destViewController.typeForm = @"accessControlForm";
[self presentViewController:destViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I put that code in my second view:

```
NSLog(@"formView : %@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

It displays (null).
I tried to find the way to display the second view in "push controller", it works, but the problem is that I cannot display a push mode in formSheet appearance (can't I?)...

Comment: you have added your viewController to one UINavigationController?

Comment: Yep I confirm. I precise that I use a Storyboard